# Составить объединенный запрос к базе

Tags: база-данных, запрос, sql

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, с запросом. Есть запрос

```
$this->db->query("SELECT users.* FROM users 
           JOIN sessions ON users.nickname=sessions.nickname
           WHERE sessions.last_activity > ".(time()-180));
```

а мне нужно сделать аналогичный запрос только не SELECT а UPDATE, что то типа

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE users SET users.activity='Online' JOIN sessions ON users.nickname=sessions.nickname WHERE sessions.last_activity>".(time()-180));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE users, sessions SET user.activity = 'Online' WHERE user.nickname=session.nickname AND sessions.last_activity>".(time()-180)."
```

P.S. Вы уверен, что стоит использовать nickname? Если на этом поле нет индекса хотя бы в одной таблице, запрос будет работать очень долго. Обычно используется поле userid или аналогичное с типом int и primary index на нем.

Comment: primary index  - это наверное первичный ключ для поля? Я сделал такой запрос, так как в одной таблице хранится информация о сессии и времени пользователя, а вывод данных пользователей идет из другой таблицы, наверное мне стоило сделать по другому. К примеру отслеживать действия пользователя через JS, сравнивать их с текущей сессией и обновлять данные сразу в таблицы users и не делать такие запутанные запросы. Еще не совсем понятно, как отследить через сессии (стандартные php) время последнего запроса к серверу от конкретного пользователя

Comment: Если стоит задача отслеживать точное время последнего обращения к сайту, то придется при каждом обращении слать UPDATE session SET activity = NOW()

Не совсем понятно, в какой момент вы собираетесь делать UPDATE, указанный в вопросе изначально. Проще уж при выводе джойнить (LEFT JOIN) session и выводить "онлайн", если последняя сессия пользователя была зарегистрирована не позднее time-180

Answer (score 0):

Замените join на подзапрос:
`update users set activity='Online' where nickname in (select nickname from sessions where sessions.last_activity>".(time()-180)));`

Comment: Zufir, не совсем понял, так что ли 
("SELECT users.* FROM users UPDATE users set activity='Online' 
where nickname in (select `nickname` from `sessions` where sessions.last_activity>".(time()-180)));

Comment: а select-то зачем?

Comment: Zufir, ("UPDATE users SET activity='Online' 
 WHERE nickname in (select nickname from sessions 
        where sessions.last_activity>".(time()-180)));
получается скобка лишняя, в конце, если ее убрать, то вылетает синтаксическая ошибка. Поправите пожалуйста, где я не правильно написал

Comment: Это ж PHP? Тогда, наверное, вот так:
`$this->db->query("UPDATE users SET activity='Online' WHERE nickname in (select nickname from sessions where sessions.last_activity>".(time()-180).")");` Но на PHP я не почти не писал, так что по синтаксису помню очень мало :)

Comment: Zufir, благодарю! Вы наверное не фанат php? На чем то другом пишите приложения?

Comment: если `time()` это вызов функции которая возвращает текущее время то лучше `time()-180` заменить аналогичным `sql` кодом

Comment: jmu, можно пример этого кода? А то я не понял о чем вы

Comment: я имел в виду следующее (на примере оракл):

    UPDATE users 
       SET users.activity='Online' 
      JOIN sessions ON users.nickname=sessions.nickname 
     WHERE sessions.last_activity > sysdate - interval '3' minute